# Zero-downtime SSL certificate update

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, ssl-certificate

My SSL certificates expire after 90 days, and I can generate a fresh certificate on request. (I get free certificates using [Let's Encrypt Without Sudo](https://github.com/diafygi/letsencrypt-nosudo).)

At the moment I have a simple HTTPS server which I need to reboot to update the certificates:

```
require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cert.pem')
}, app).listen(443);
```

How can I design my HTTPS server so that I can update my SSL certificate without a server reboot?

Comment: How did you handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, but compared to the reboot strategy all these options have a performance degradation.

One possibility is to check the last update time of the cert file on every request (or at regular basis). If the timestamp changed (compare to the one you have in memory), you can reload the content of the key and cert or spawn a new server instance that replaces the previous one.

I'm not very familiar with NodeJS, hence I don't know how the `https` package stores the current https server instance. Given I don't see any receiver, I believe it may be stored in some sort of default variable. Ideally, your implementation should replace such value (unless you can replace the specific `key` and `cert` setting values accessing the instantiated server.